# grunt-text-replace doesn't work

Tags: replace, gruntjs, str-replace

I installed `grunt-text-replace` with `npm install grunt-text-replace --save-dev` command and add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');` to `gruntfile.js` and add write this:

```
replace: {
    example: {
        src: ['css/mystyle.css'],
        overwrite: true,      
        replacements: [{
            from: 'wizard',                   // string replacement 
            to: 'wizardstep'
        }]
    }
}
```

then run `grunt replace` in command line and after that show me `done, without error` but my replacement doesn't work and applied.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I entered path incorrectly and other hand  `grunt-text-replace` doesn't show me message if source file path incorrect.

> just I correct source path